# Testing the pressed state of a Pressable

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component that renders a React Native `Pressable` and uses the `pressed` state to alter the display:

```
<Pressable testID="t">
  {({ pressed }) => <Text style={pressed ? pressedStyle : unPressedStyle }>{title}</Text>
<Pressable>
```

This works fine, but when I run a test coverage report, the `pressed` state is skipped. This happens even if I fire a `press` event on the pressable, for example:

```
const { getByTestID } = render(<PressableComponent />);
const pressable = getByTestID('t');
fireEvent.press(pressable);
```

Is there any way to trigger the `pressed` state during testing so that I can test that branch?

Comment: I know they're not exactly the same thing but do you get much joy with testing `onPressIn` or `onPressOut`? According to https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable it triggers these before triggering `onPress`. This is not the solution but may assist with debugging the issue.

Comment: @ourmaninamsterdam thanks for the suggestion... I'm more interested in improving test coverage rather than finding specific issues.

Comment: No problem. @Explosion Pills. Let us know if you manage to resolve this as I'm keen to know for my own purposes.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`testOnly_pressed`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable#testonly_pressed) property of RN Pressable component. If set to `true` it simulates a pressed state in tests.

```
<Pressable testID="t" testOnly_pressed={isStatusPressedForTest}>
  {({ pressed }) => <Text style={pressed ? pressedStyle : unPressedStyle }>{title}</Text>
<Pressable>


const { getByTestID } = render(<PressableComponent isStatusPressedForTest />);
```

No need to fire the press event then anymore.
Just expect what you expect to happen in status `pressed`.